# Can not Index Magento with more than 2 million of product

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have a website with approx 2 million of products, I am facing the problem while doing the reindexing. I have tried to do it by using the SSH `php indexer.php --reindexall` but it is taking too much of the time and I have also tried to do it one by one by using the commands below:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
php indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
```

But the problem is coming in these Three

```
    php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
    php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
    php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
```

it is showing the error **General error: 1206 The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size'**

1. I have added and increased the innodb_buffer_pool_size up to 40G and the syntax is given below innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G and restarted mysql.
2. I have deleted all the index files from the var/locks and am trying to do the reindexing again but the problem is same.

Please suggest me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

clear this indexing table: "index_event"

and Rewrite URL table is also clear if not Rewrite URL in admin side: "core_url_rewrite"

remove file in this folder location : magento/var/locks

than after reindexing.